# Get apache server version with command line tools

Tags: linux, apache, awk, grep, tr

I use this command to get the apache server version:

`apachectl -V | grep -i "Server version" | tr "/" " " | awk '{ print $4 }'`

But this does not work on every system. Sometimes i get some other output before my server version output.

[image]

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
>   globally to suppress this message

The question is why do i get this output, even though grep should filter it off? I know that i can suppress it, but why does it even show even though i use grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message probably goes to the standard error, not standard output. To hide it, redirect stderr to nowhere:

```
apachectl -V 2>/dev/null | grep ...
```